# errno 9 bad file descriptor, basic python server socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm having difficulty with getting data from a server in python. I'm getting Errno 9 bad file descriptor and a 'connection was reset' message on my browser whenever I try to access my test html file. The code is as follows:

```
#import socket module
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 12000
#Prepare a sever socket
serverSocket.bind(("", serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)


while True:
    #Establish the connection
    print 'Ready to serve...'
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()#Accepts a TCP client    connection, waiting until connection arrives
    print 'Required connection', addr
    try:

        message = connectionSocket.recv(64)
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()

        #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n')


        #Send the content of the requested file to the client

        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close() 

    except IOError:
        #Send response message for file not found
        connectionSocket.send('404 Not Found!')
        #Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
        serverSocket.close()
```

I can't tell why i am getting this error. I have tried removing the close from right outside the outputdata for loop, which didn't work either. I tried changing the server port, and closing the socket and server in different orders.

the full trackback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UDPServer.py", line 13, in <module>
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()#Accepts a TCP client   connection, waiting until connection arrives
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 202, in accept
    sock, addr = self._sock.accept()
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
socket.error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the socket once it's closed. [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.close) for `socket.close()` say:

> All future operations on the socket object will fail.

You could create a new socket in the loop.